# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method load(Landroid/net/Uri;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest;

Tags: android, android-glide, nosuchmethoderror

I have been using `TedBottomPicker` library for picking image from **camera** and **gallery**. Also am using `Glide` in my project. Recently i have updated `Glide` library to latest version and `TedBottomPicker` library also. Now i am facing problem while am calling the accessing the **camera** or **gallery** using the `TedBottomPicker` library.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.fooddoof.fuddict, PID: 2284
>                                                                   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   load(Landroid/net/Uri;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest; in
>   class Lcom/bumptech/glide/RequestManager; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager' appears in
>   /data/app/com.fooddoof.fuddict-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>                                                                       at gun0912.tedbottompicker.adapter.GalleryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(GalleryAdapter.java:163)
>                                                                       at gun0912.tedbottompicker.adapter.GalleryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(GalleryAdapter.java:32)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6508)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6541)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5484)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5750)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5589)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5585)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2231)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:610)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3135)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:719)
>                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:791)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                       at   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
>   12-14 09:52:42.908 2284-2284/com.fooddoof.fuddict E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
>                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
>                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
>                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
>                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

The above exception is shown in logcat. I have tried with other different library also but this error is seen.

my dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'gun0912.ted:tedbottompicker:1.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
}
```

Accessing library

```
PermissionListener permissionlistener1 = new PermissionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPermissionGranted() {

              TedBottomPicker tedBottomPicker = new TedBottomPicker.Builder(PostActivity.this)
                            .setOnImageSelectedListener(new TedBottomPicker.OnImageSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onImageSelected(Uri uri) {
                                    // here is selected uri
                                }
                            })
                            .create();

 tedBottomPicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Gallery Adapter.java

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<descusers> images;
private Context mContext;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView thumbnail;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }
}

public GalleryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<descusers> images) {
    mContext = context;
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public GalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbnail, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    descusers image  = images.get(position);
    Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getimage())
            .into(holder.thumbnail);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}


public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private GalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final GalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Downgrade the glide version it will work...`RequestManager` class issue in 4.0...Refer this https://github.com/myinnos/AwesomeImagePicker/issues/11

Comment: @JacobCelestine - which part of code do you need to fix this problem?

Comment: @JacobCelestine - Question updated with galleryadapter

Comment: s@JacobCelestine -  Same error appears

Comment: @user2269164 Is this after you tried my _answer_? (Comment on the answer if its about the answer, I didn't get notification in case you answered after my answer)

Comment: @JacobCelestine - I tried with your answer and i received the same error.

Comment: @user2269164 I just realized what the problem is. I updated my answer mentioning the same. Do check it.

Answer (score 6):

I understand what the error is. The library *TedBottomPicker* taht you are using uses glide version 3.6.1. But you use v4 of glide. This leads to error as both cannot be used at the same time. You have these options now:

- Either *downgrade your project* to use the version by TedBottomPicker
- Use *some other project* other than TedBottomPicker
- Ask the developer of *TedBottomPicker* to upgrade his project
- Import *TedBottomPicker* to your project and rewrite every method yourself

Hope this helps.

Comment: This shouldn't cause the error, gradle should automatically resolve gradle conflict by using the highest version which is v4 glide. I think what caused it is TedBottom is trying to use a v3 Glide method but it isn't found in v4.

Comment: That is exactly what I said -_-

Answer (score 4):

## Use this `new Glide4Engine()` instead of `new GlideEngine()`

```
 Matisse.from(ChatActivity.this)
                .choose(MimeType.ofAll(), false)
                .countable(true)
                .maxSelectable(MAX_SELECTABLE)
                .restrictOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)
                .thumbnailScale(0.85f)
                .imageEngine(new Glide4Engine()) // for Glide V4
                .maxOriginalSize(10)
                //  .imageEngine(new GlideEngine()) // for Glide V3
                .forResult(PICK_GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

## Glide4Engine.java

```
public class Glide4Engine implements ImageEngine {
    @Override
    public void loadThumbnail(Context context, int resize, Drawable placeholder, ImageView imageView, Uri uri) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap() // some .jpeg files are actually gif
                .load(uri)
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .override(resize, resize)
                        .placeholder(placeholder)
                        .centerCrop())
                .into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadGifThumbnail(Context context, int resize, Drawable placeholder, ImageView imageView,
                                 Uri uri) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap() // some .jpeg files are actually gif
                .load(uri)
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .override(resize, resize)
                        .placeholder(placeholder)
                        .centerCrop())
                .into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadImage(Context context, int resizeX, int resizeY, ImageView imageView, Uri uri) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .override(resizeX, resizeY)
                        .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                        .fitCenter())
                .into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadGifImage(Context context, int resizeX, int resizeY, ImageView imageView, Uri uri) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .asGif()
                .load(uri)
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .override(resizeX, resizeY)
                        .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                        .fitCenter())
                .into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportAnimatedGif() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

I also facing this issue but i solved this using latest version of glide

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of Glide to fix the issue.

In plain terms, the version of TedBottomPicker which you are currently using, requires a corresponding version of glide to work correctly, but your current version of glide basically can't satisfy its requirements thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using glide:4.1.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).